# how to create summary table in Jira based on components?

Tags: jira

we have a project in Jira and it has 10 components. how can I create a summary table(gadget) to show the open tickets for each components?

Below is sample of desired output:

```
ComponentName NumberOfTickets
component1  5
component2  1
component3  0
component4  10
```

Thanks!

edit:
mdoar's solution worked for my original questions. Is it possible to have additional field as group, such as status, disired output

```
ComponentName Open InProgress QA Closed
component1  5 4 1 10
component2  1 0 1 3
component3  0 1 5 9
component4  10 1 4 6
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a filter such as: project = FOO and resolution is empty
Save the filter
Create a new Issue Statistics gadget on a dashboard and configure it to use the saved filter
Choose Component as the field to group by.